# How to teach ConTeXt to recognize and format custom syntax?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I have a document filled with editor's comments, appearing like this:

```
\starttext

    This [is ]some text with
    comment[s] added to show
    corrections to erro[r]s.

\stoptext
```

I need to make the comments in bold, so that they are more visible. The result would be the same as this:

```
\starttext

    This {\bf [is ]}some text with
    comment{\bf [s]} added to show
    corrections to erro{\bf [r]}s.

\stoptext
```

Is there any way to teach ConTeXt to format all of the text appearing in the square brackets in this format and the square brackets, without manually adding the `{\bf *}` syntax to the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the annotations are so short that they do not span multiple lines
you can use an *input handler*:

```
\startluacode
  local lpeg         = require "lpeg"
  local lpegmatch    = lpeg.match
  local Cs, P, V     = lpeg.Cs, lpeg.P, lpeg.V
  local lbrak        = P "["
  local rbrak        = P "]"
  local inner        = P { lbrak * (V (1) + (1 - rbrak))^1 * rbrak }
  local outer        = (lbrak / [[{\bf[]])
                     * (inner + (1 - rbrak))^1
                     * (rbrak / "]}")
  local p_rewrite    = Cs ((outer + 1)^0)

  resolvers.installinputlinehandler (function (line)
    return lpegmatch (p_rewrite, line)
  end)
\stopluacode

\starttext

    This [is ]some [[text] with]
    comment[s] added to show
    corrections to erro[r]s.

    \blank [3*line] %% <= fail

    Unmatching [[[brackets are
    unaffected]. [Nesting [is]]
    fine, though.

\stoptext
```

The example code rewrites input lines by means of an LPEG substitution
pattern.
Nesting matching pairs of braces inside the highlighted region nesting
is permitted, unmatched opening brackets are ignored.

There is a catch, though: the substitution is applied before TeX has
the chance to process macros.
Since in Context square brackets usually delimit macro arguments, you
can expect a lot of interference if the files contain further markup.
If that is the case you might want to switch to a different pair of
delimiters like '<', '>'.